# Should I use custom setters in EF Core models?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I was just wondering if i should use custom setters in EF Core models. Consider this very simple example:

```
using System;

namespace EFTest.Models
{
    public class Reservation
    {
        public int ReservationId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
        public int ResourceId { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public Resource Resource { get; set; }
    }

    public class Resource
    {
        public int ResourceId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The issue being that when i have to save a model, and add an instance of a class to it, it handles getting the foreign key from said added instance just fine, like so:

```
public void SaveReservation()
{
    var db = new Datebase();
    var reservation = new Reservation(){ Start = new DateTime().Now, End = new DateTime().Now.AddDays(7)};

    reservation.Resource = db.Resources.Find(2);
    reservation.Customer = db.Customers.Find(4);

    db.Reservations.Add(reservation);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

but if i set the foreign key property for customer, but then add the instance of a resource, forexample, it is utterly unable to handle getting the foreignkey, like so:

```
public void SaveReservation()
{
    var db = new Datebase();
    var reservation = new Reservation(){ Start = new DateTime().Now, End = new DateTime().Now.AddDays(7)};

    reservation.Resource = db.Resources.Find(2);
    reservation.CustomerId = 4;

    db.Reservations.Add(reservation);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Resulting in a sqlite exception 19, 'failing to get foreignkey' or somesuch.

The only solution i can think of is to do custom setters and getters to handle setting the property based on the key, and vice versa, e.g.:

```
using System;

namespace EFTest.Models
{
    public class Reservation
    {
        public int ReservationId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
        public int ResourceId 
        { 
            get
            {
                if(_Resource != null)
                {
                    return _Resource.ResourceId;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            } 
            set
            {
                if(_Resource != null && !_Resource.ResourceId.Equals(value))
                {
                    _Resource = null;
                }
            } 
        }
        public int CustomerId
        { 
            get
            {
                if(_Customer != null)
                {
                    return _Customer.CustomerId;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            } 
            set
            {
                if(_Customer != null && !_Customer.CustomerId.Equals(value))
                {
                    _Customer = null;
                }
            } 
        }

        public Customer Customer 
        { 
            get
            {
                return _Customer;
            } 
            set
            {
                _Customer = value;
                if(value != null)
                {
                    CustomerId = _Customer.CustomerId;
                }
                else
                {
                    CustomerId = 0;
                }
            } 
        }
        private Customer _Customer { get; set; }

        public Resource Resource
        { 
            get
            {
                return _Resource;
            } 
            set
            {
                _Resource = value;
                if(value != null)
                {
                    ResourceId = _Resource.ResourceId;
                }
                else
                {
                    ResourceId = 0;
                }
            } 
        }
        private Resource _Resource { get; set; }
    }

    public class Resource
    {
        public int ResourceId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But I am not at all certain this is a good way to handle the issue, can someone provide some insight on whether it is a good way to handle it? and whether there is a better one?

thank you.

Comment: Instead of this incomprehensible `new DateTime().Now + new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)`, why are you not using just `DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)`?

Comment: Because i brainfarted. I'll correct it, but it's really completely irrelevant to the question how that is done. The values there is just to provide some context. :)

Comment: failing to get foreign key? I've never seen that exception and have been working with sqlite with EF quite a bit. What is the exact exception message? if it's the FK constraint, you know why. But no, you shouldn't use custom getters or setters in your BO's, those should reflect your db schema pretty neatly.

Comment: I can't seem to provoke the error again, so i can't say exactly. But it was code "sqlite error: 19 foreign key contraint failed" 

Or something like that.

Comment: That type of error sounds like the foreign key that was fed doesn't actually match up with anything on the other side. For example, if you set the user id (as the foreign key) to 4, but there's actually no user with PK = 4, then you would likely receive an error like that. It can also occur if the user id is not set, i.e. 0 or null, as it's basically the same situation: there won't be a user with that PK.

Comment: Well, I did check that back then but there was no issue there, the pk did exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thank you to DevilSuichiro  for providing the very clear and useful answer:

"But no, you shouldn't use custom getters or setters in your BO's, those should reflect your db schema pretty neatly."